# Batch Script: Can't get the loop to correctly check

Tags: windows, batch-file

Ok, I almost have this done but need some help getting the  bugs out.

The User Delete function works great and out puts the TEMP file like so:

```
"All Users"
"Default"
"Default User"
"Public"
```

":UserDeleteJoin" will output the following if i check it with an echo

```
Public,Default User,Default,All Users
```

The Full code that does what I have describe is as follows:

```
set UsersPath=%systemdrive%\Users\
DEL /F /Q /A:H %UsersPath%\desktop.ini 2>nul>nul
forfiles /p %UsersPath% /m * /d -45 /c "cmd /c echo @file">%TEMP%\users.temp
FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1 delims=" %%P IN (%TEMP%\users.temp) DO CALL:UserDeleteJoin %%P
set userdelete=%userdelete:"=%
set userdelete=%userdelete:~0,-1%
echo %userdelete%
pause
GOTO:USERPRESERVE

:UserDeleteJoin
if UserDeleteJoin_Skip=="" (set userdelete=%1 & set UserDeleteJoin_Skip=1) ELSE (set userdelete=%1,%userdelete%)
goto:eof
```

So that takes care of the main issue, now only the rest of the script, which i initially got from "http://mstoneblog.wordpress.com/2010/12/08/user-profile-cleaning-script-for-windows-7/" which works great but I wanted to add the ability to only delete user profiles older than x number of days.

So I have the initial user preserve function as what I need it keeping the regular users.

```
set userpreserve="All Users,Default,Default User,Hell Bomb"
```

The next chunk of script is unaltered but i'll post it to be complete. This will include the line above and covers everything left after the :UserDeleteJoin function.

```
USERPRESERVE
set userpreserve="All Users,Default,Default User,Hell Bomb"

FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a IN ('reg query "hklm\software\microsoft\windows nt\currentversion\profilelist"^|find /i "s-1-5-21"') DO CALL :REGCHECK "%%a"
GOTO VERIFY

:REGCHECK
set SPACECHECK=
FOR /f "tokens=3,4" %%b in ('reg query %1 /v ProfileImagePath') DO SET USERREGPATH=%%b %%c
FOR /f "tokens=2" %%d in ('echo %USERREGPATH%') DO SET SPACECHECK=%%d
IF ["%SPACECHECK%"]==[""] GOTO REGCHECK2
GOTO USERCHECK

:REGCHECK2
FOR /f "tokens=3" %%g in ('reg query %1 /v ProfileImagePath') DO SET USERREGPATH=%%g
GOTO USERCHECK

:USERCHECK
FOR /f "tokens=3 delims=\" %%e in ('echo %USERREGPATH%') DO SET USERREG=%%e
FOR /f "tokens=1 delims=." %%f IN ('echo %USERREG%') DO SET USERREGPARSE=%%f
ECHO %USERPRESERVE%|find /I "%USERREGPARSE%" > NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL=1 GOTO DELETECHECK
IF ERRORLEVEL=0 GOTO SKIP

:DELETECHECK
ECHO %userdelete%|find /I "%USERREGPARSE%" > NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL=1 GOTO SKIP
IF ERRORLEVEL=0 GOTO CL
GOTO:EOF

:SKIP
ECHO Skipping user clean for %USERREG%
GOTO :EOF

:CLEAN
ECHO Cleaning user profile for %USERREG%
::rmdir "C:\Users\%USERREG%" /s /q > NUL
ECHO Cleaning user registry for %USERREG%
::reg delete %1 /f
::IF EXIST "C:\Users\%USERREG%" GOTO RETRYCLEAN1
GOTO :EOF
```

Im pretty sure that the issue is with the error check but I can't really tell, cuz it only wants to hit the profiles "Trinity Tech Corp" and "Hell Bomb" and ignores all the other profiles despite what other settings are. Can't seem to narrow down the issue more than that unfortunately, but that might be because i have been looking at it for WAY to long.

The part of the script that i added to the original script was as follow:

```
IF ERRORLEVEL=1 GOTO DELETECHECK
```

And

```
:DELETECHECK
ECHO %userdelete%|find /I "%USERREGPARSE%" > NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL=1 GOTO SKIP
IF ERRORLEVEL=0 GOTO CL
GOTO:EOF
```

The output that is given to me when I run the script is as follows, which it should skip both of those folders, but it does not delete the other user profiles.

```
Skipping user clean for Trinity Tech
Skipping user clean for Hell Bomb
```

Other solutions:
I  was thinking this could be made a lot simpler is i could figure out how to get FORFILES to list all folders that are NOT older than 45 days then i could simply do another loop like i did for ":UserDeleteJoin" and would not have to edit the main part of the original script. If anyone has any idea how I can do that i can avoid all the issues i am having now.

Full Script

```
@ECHO OFF

set UsersPath=%systemdrive%\Users\
DEL /F /Q /A:H %UsersPath%\desktop.ini 2>nul>nul
forfiles /p %UsersPath% /m * /d -45 /c "cmd /c echo @file">%TEMP%\users.temp
FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1 delims=" %%P IN (%TEMP%\users.temp) DO CALL:UserDeleteJoin %%P
set userdelete=%userdelete:"=%
set userdelete=%userdelete:~0,-1%
GOTO:USERPRESERVE

:UserDeleteJoin
if UserDeleteJoin_Skip=="" (set userdelete=%1 & set UserDeleteJoin_Skip=1) ELSE (set userdelete=%1,%userdelete%)
goto:eof

:USERPRESERVE
set userpreserve="All Users,Default,Default User,Hell Bomb"

FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a IN ('reg query "hklm\software\microsoft\windows nt\currentversion\profilelist"^|find /i "s-1-5-21"') DO CALL :REGCHECK "%%a"
GOTO VERIFY

:REGCHECK
set SPACECHECK=
FOR /f "tokens=3,4" %%b in ('reg query %1 /v ProfileImagePath') DO SET USERREGPATH=%%b %%c
FOR /f "tokens=2" %%d in ('echo %USERREGPATH%') DO SET SPACECHECK=%%d
IF ["%SPACECHECK%"]==[""] GOTO REGCHECK2
GOTO USERCHECK

:REGCHECK2
FOR /f "tokens=3" %%g in ('reg query %1 /v ProfileImagePath') DO SET USERREGPATH=%%g
GOTO USERCHECK

:USERCHECK
FOR /f "tokens=3 delims=\" %%e in ('echo %USERREGPATH%') DO SET USERREG=%%e
FOR /f "tokens=1 delims=." %%f IN ('echo %USERREG%') DO SET USERREGPARSE=%%f
ECHO %USERPRESERVE%|find /I "%USERREGPARSE%" > NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL=1 GOTO DELETECHECK
IF ERRORLEVEL=0 GOTO SKIP

:DELETECHECK
FOR /f "tokens=3 delims=\" %%e in ('echo %USERREGPATH%') DO SET USERREG=%%e
FOR /f "tokens=1 delims=." %%f IN ('echo %USERREG%') DO SET USERREGPARSE=%%f
ECHO %userdelete%|find /I "%USERREGPARSE%" > NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL=1 GOTO SKIP
IF ERRORLEVEL=0 GOTO CL
GOTO:EOF

:SKIP
ECHO Skipping user clean for %USERREG%
GOTO :EOF

:CLEAN
ECHO Cleaning user profile for %USERREG%
::rmdir "C:\Users\%USERREG%" /s /q > NUL
ECHO Cleaning user registry for %USERREG%
::reg delete %1 /f
::IF EXIST "C:\Users\%USERREG%" GOTO RETRYCLEAN1
GOTO :EOF

:RETRYCLEAN1
ECHO Retrying clean of user profile %USERREG%
rmdir "C:\Users\%USERREG%" /s /q > NUL
IF EXIST "C:\Users\%USERREG%" GOTO RETRYCLEAN2
GOTO :EOF

:RETRYCLEAN2
ECHO Retrying clean of user profile %USERREG%
rmdir "C:\Users\%USERREG%" /s /q > NUL
GOTO :EOF

:VERIFY
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%g IN ('reg query "hklm\software\microsoft\windows nt\currentversion\profilelist"^|find /i "s-1-5-21"') DO CALL :REGCHECKV "%%g"
GOTO REPORT

:REGCHECKV
set SPACECHECKV=
FOR /f "tokens=3,4" %%h in ('reg query %1 /v ProfileImagePath') DO SET USERREGPATHV=%%h %%i
FOR /f "tokens=2" %%j in ('echo %USERREGPATHV%') DO SET SPACECHECKV=%%j
IF ["%SPACECHECKV%"]==[""] GOTO REGCHECKV2
GOTO USERCHECKV

:REGCHECKV2
FOR /f "tokens=3" %%k in ('reg query %1 /v ProfileImagePath') DO SET USERREGPATHV=%%k
GOTO USERCHECKV

:USERCHECKV
FOR /f "tokens=3 delims=\" %%l in ('echo %USERREGPATHV%') DO SET USERREGV=%%l
FOR /f "tokens=1 delims=." %%m IN ('echo %USERREGV%') DO SET USERREGPARSEV=%%m
ECHO %USERPRESERVE%|find /I "%USERREGPARSEV%" > NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL=1 GOTO VERIFYERROR
IF ERRORLEVEL=0 GOTO :EOF

:VERIFYERROR
SET USERERROR=YES
GOTO :EOF

:REPORT
IF [%USERERROR%]==[YES] (
        set RESULT=FAILURE
)       ELSE (
        set RESULT=SUCCESS
)

Pause
:EXIT
exit

:EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

From the original question:

> I was thinking this could be made a lot simpler is i could figure out
>   how to get FORFILES to list all folders that are NOT older than 45
>   days

You have already got the list of folders that are older then 45 days. You can simply use FINDSTR to look for entries that are not in that list.

```
forfiles /p %UsersPath% /m * /c "cmd /c echo @file" | findstr /vixg:"%TEMP%\users.temp"
```

---

Are you sure you want to delete "desktop.ini"? Or are you just deleting it so that you only have folders to deal with?

If you only want FORFILES to list folders, you can do the following:

```
forfiles /p %UsersPath% /m * /d -45 /c "cmd /c if @isdir=="TRUE" echo @file">%TEMP%\users.temp
```